# Is 'face falls' an idiom?

Tags: vocabulary

> Harry put the plates of egg and bacon on the table, which was
>   difficult as there wasn't much room. Dudley, meanwhile, was counting
>   his presents. ***His face fell***.
>
> "Thirty-six," he said, looking up at his mother and father. "That's two less than last year."
>
> -- *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone* by J.K. Rowling.

It seems like the highlighted part mean *he disappointed*. But I don’t find any account for it in dictionaries. What does it exactly mean?

Comment: http://www.dictionarist.com/his+face+fell

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've more or less got it right. "His face fell" is a common idiom which means "His face changed to a look of disappointment".

For dictionary definitions try [Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fall):

> [no object] (of someone’s face) show dismay or disappointment by
>   appearing to droop: her face fell as she thought about her life with
>   George

or [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fall):

> 6 e : to assume a look of shame,
>   disappointment, or dejection *his face fell*